# What dictates whether an orbit gets disrupted or stabilised due to an orbital resonance?

Tags: physics, orbital-mechanics, astronomy, solar-system, astrophysics

### Context:

I've got an asteroid belt analogue situated between a Gas giant and a Super-earth. I knew about resonances, so I started calculating them and placing some of them in the belt, especially ones that would be convergent between the giant and the super-earth, to know where the gaps would be present. Then I realised that resonances also tend to create stable orbits, like the orbits of Galilean Moons.

### Question:

What dictates whether an orbital resonance causes a stability of the orbit (like the Galilean Moons) or disruptions of the orbit (like the Kirkwood gaps)?

Comment: Why did you not take your own, basic research further; at least far enough to what dictated disruption or stability, rather than simply noting that instances such as Galilean Moons Kirkwood gaps existed?

When you knew about resonances and so started calculating them and placing some in the belt, how far did you get and what told you that you'd gone wrong?

How could any of that matter in SE Worldbuilding, where all the rules are defined by the Builder, ie, by you?

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: Each resonance can be associated with a certain region of space within which it can affect objects. You can calculate the size of this region from the properties of the resonance and the orbits lying near it. If the regions from two neighboring resonances happen to nearly overlap, there's the potential for instability.

---

Although resonance stability is a complicated issue, it sometimes becomes a question of comparing neighboring resonances. Say we have a planet -- we can start with the gas giant -- creating mean motion resonances, i.e. resonances arising from ratios of its orbital period to the orbital period of a small test mass, like an asteroid. You can define the "width" of a resonance, which describes the amplitude of oscillations around it. If the combined halfwidths of neighboring first-order resonances$^{\dagger}$ is comparable to their separation, then the resonances become unstable: the asteroid can oscillate from one to the other and experience chaotic motion, which in many (though not all) cases can lead to ejection from the system.

Quantitatively, some treatments say that test particles will experience chaotic motion if a quantity called the overlap ratio, $\gamma$, becomes at least $2/3$ (see section 3.3. of [these notes](https://www.lpl.arizona.edu/%7Erenu/malhotra_preprints/unesco_malhotra_rev2.pdf)); this is related to the better-known [Chirikov criterion](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chirikov_criterion). $\gamma$ is defined as the ratio of the sum of the halfwidths to the distance between the resonances:
$$\gamma\equiv\frac{\Delta n}{\delta n},\quad\delta n\equiv\left(\frac{p+1}{p+2}-\frac{p}{p+1}\right)n_p,\quad\Delta n\approx3.73p^{1/3}\mu^{2/3}n_p$$
where $\mu\equiv m_p/m*$ is the ratio of the mass of the planet responsible for the resonance to the mass of the star, and $n_p$ is the planet's mean motion.

Since $\delta n\approx p^{-2}n_p$ for large $p$, this essentially reduces to the criterion
$p^{-1}\lesssim 2.1\mu^{2/7}$ for large $p$ (otherwise, use the exact expression for $\delta n$). You can also phrase this in terms of the planet's semimajor axis $a_p$ and the asteroid's semimajor axis $a$:
$$\left|\frac{a-a_p}{a_p}\right|\lesssim1.4\mu^{2/7}$$
You're likely also interested in resonances arising from the presence of two bodies -- the gas giant *and* the super-Earth. This means we've now gone from the restricted three-body problem (the star, the gas giant and the asteroid) to a four-body problem (those three as well as the super-Earth) and is harder to deal with analytically. You might, though, be able to find related definitions of resonance widths and separations, and again consider the question of resonance overlap. I unfortunately don't know enough to say anything specific!

You could also attempt to simply run numerical simulations and see what happens. [REBOUND](https://rebound.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is an $N$-body simulation code I know some folks here have used; I haven't tried it out personally, but it's pretty well-documented and is easier than writing something from scratch yourself (unless you already have this sort of code lying around. . .).

---

$^{\dagger}$This means a pair of resonances like $p:p+1$ and $p+1:p+2$. An example would be the $1:2$ and $2:3$ resonances, where $p=1$.

Comment: All of that sounds like what I'm looking for, but the vocabulary is a bit too adcanced for me, could you for example explain what's a halfwidth, what are those oscilations in the resonance, what's a separation, or just in gnereal, the entire text but in the simpler language? I know where each of the resonance will lie in the orbit, which I think is what you're trying to explain, but I want to know when such resknance will create a gap in the rings and when will it create a stable orbit

Comment: @Yulian Sorry for taking so long to get around to this -- I've added a short intro paragraph! In words, you calculate the region of orbits affected by each resonance; if two neighboring regions overlap, then the pair of resonances will lead to instability.